# ASP.NET Databinding Template: Escape Tags in a Server Tag

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, templates

I'm doing some databinding inside a ListView ItemTemplate, but I suspect this is a problem for any databinding/template situation.  I want to write something like:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidPositionID" Value="<%#Eval("PositionID") %>" />
```

But I get a YSOD with an error message that the server tag is not well formed.  How do I persist non-visible data inside my ListViewItem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes (`''`) to wrap anything with `""` inside the value so the start/stop pairs match:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" 
                 ID="hidPositionID" 
                 Value='<%#Eval("PositionID") %>' />
```